# Is it true that if $A$ is unitary diagonalizable and $B$ is similar to $A$ then $B$ is also unitary diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is it true that if $A$ is unitary diagonalizable (i.e. $A$ is normal) and $B$ is similar to $A$ then $B$ is also unitary diagonalizable (i.e. $B$ is normal) ?

Here are my thoughts:

If $A$ is unitary diagonalizable matrix then there exist unitary matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $P^*AP=D$.  $(*)$

We also know from the Spectral theorem that $A$ is normal ($\because$ $A$ is unitary diagonalizable $ \iff A$ is normal).

From the fact that $B$ is similar to $A$ we can derive that there exists invertible matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}BQ=A$.

Finally, by replacing $A$ in $(*)$ with $Q^{-1}BQ$ we get:

$$ P^*Q^{-1}BQP=D \ \ (**)$$

The only thing I can derive from this equation $(**)$ is that $B$ is diagonalizable, because :

$$ P^*Q^{-1}BQP=D \implies P^{-1}Q^{-1}BQP=D \implies (QP)^{-1}B(QP)=D \implies C^{-1}BC=D$$

Am I missing something? Is it possible that I can also derive that $B$ is **unitary** diagonalizable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\0 & 2\end{array}\right), \quad B=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 3\\0 & 2\end{array}\right),\quad Q=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 3\\0 & 1\end{array}\right). $$

Comment: Thank you. Very nice counter example. I'm curious - how did you come up with this example?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB I knew that the answer to your question is NO, so I had to look for $A$ which is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix and for $B$ which is not but is similar to $A$. And, by the way, questions about matrices is often useful to check by $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ matrices.

Answer (score 2):

For a unitarily diagonalizable matrix, eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.
Thus let $A$ be a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues and $B = S A S^{-1}$.  Then $B$ is similar to $A$, and the columns of $S$ are eigenvectors.
If $S$ has columns that are not orthogonal, $B$ is not unitarily diagonalizable.